# What is the use of Java Char array?

Tags: java, arrays, string, character

I have a Java code associated with `BigInteger class` below,

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class Main
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        BigInteger num = new BigInteger("123456789101112131415");

        String str;
        char []Char = new char[10];

        str = num.toString();
        Char = str.toCharArray();

        System.out.println(str.length());
        System.out.println(Char.length);
    }
}
```

In that code, I have a `BigInteger` num which has 21 digits. I converted it into a `String` then into a `Char array`. But I assigned the length of that char array is just 10 before. So how this char array holds 21 characters altogether???

I really misunderstand the fact.

And one more question here, is there any method to convert BigIntegers into char arrays directly? :)

Comment: What do you think `Char = str.toCharArray();` does?

Comment: Does it convert strings to char arrays?

Sorry and pardon me if I am wrong. I am new in Java. :)

Comment: Let me rephrase, what do you think it does to the variable `Char`?

Comment: Can't it change the string into char array?

Answer (score 3):

To answer your first question, the variable `Char` (consider changing your variable names) is a reference to a `char` array. You set it to point to an array of size 10. But later, thanks to...

```
Char = str.toCharArray();
```

...you are making the reference point to another array. The original array no longer has a reference associated with it and is garbage collected.

To answer your second question, you can cascade functions in a single line.

```
char[] Char = num.toString().toCharArray();
```

Comment: That good thing for me !!! :D
at last learned something :)

Comment: As a side note, to get only the top 10 digits, like perhaps the OP was expecting their code might behave, one can use [`Arrays.copyOf(num.toString().toCharArray(), 10)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf-char:A-int-). Not that I see any particular reason to do it here, but I guess it's worth mentioning.

Comment: @Radiodef pleasure :)

Comment: @ShahShishir Please consider accepting this answer if it helped you. Thanks.